# Use Porter's stemmer from a List?

Tags: java, list, stemming

I have a List of words that I am trying to stem. How can I use the Porter Stemmer with the List? I only found information about stemming using a text file, but I am not sure how to adapt it for the List.

Comment: Is it a `List<String>` ? why not just apply a PortStemmer on each `String` in the `List`

Comment: Yes, it's a List<String>. Do you have any example of how it can be applied in a single string?

Comment: [Here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/lucene-1.3-final/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PorterStemmer.java.shtml) is an example to get you started. Look for method `public String stem(String s)`